# NSData getBytes Randomly Returns Garbage

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdata

I'm trying to save and load a custom file format in an iOS app. The format stores various data, but among it is the name a user entered for a map. I found that at random, as I'm trying to read this map name (stored as `char`s in the file), my NSData object will read garbage. Here is my code for reading the map name (`start` is already set to the correct start location):

```
NSData* data = ....;
uint mapNameLength;
char* mapNameChar;
NSString* mapNameString;

[data getBytes:&mapNameLength range:NSMakeRange(start, 4)];
start += 4;
mapNameChar = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * mapNameLength);
[data getBytes:mapNameChar range:NSMakeRange(start, mapNameLength)];
mapNameString = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:mapNameChar];

NSLog(@"mapNameLength: %u, mapNameChar: %s, Map name string: %@", mapNameLength, mapNameChar, mapNameString);
```

As you can see, I am reading the length of the name, then reading that many `char` values, then converting it into an NSString. Here is the output of the NSLog when it works (I just hit the keyboard a bunch to make a long name):

`mapNameLength: 49, mapNameChar: kandfianeifniwbvuandivbwirngiwnrivnwrivnwidnviwdv, Map name string: kandfianeifniwbvuandivbwirngiwnrivnwrivnwidnviwdv`

Here is the output of the NSLog when it doesn't work:

`mapNameLength: 49, mapNameChar: kandfianeifniwbvuandivbwirngiwnrivnwrivnwidnviwdvﬁ?p?, Map name string: (null)`

Those "?" are actually special characters that don't display here, so I added them. The first is "ETX" and the second is "SOH" in Sublime Text.

To create the file, this is what I am doing:

```
NSString* mapName = ....;
uint mapNameLength = (uint)mapName.length;
NSMutableData* data = ....;
//...
//Write file type and version here
//...
[data appendBytes:&mapNameLength length:4];
[data appendData:[mapName dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
//...
//Write other stuff
//...

NSString* path = [FileManager applicationDocumentsDirectory];
path = [path stringByAppendingFormat:@"/%@", fileName];
BOOL success = [data writeToFile:path options:NSDataWritingAtomic error:&error];
```

I've only written the file once, so I know the data is always the same. Why then, would my data object sometimes get random bytes from it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not certain, however I don't think you are storing a terminating `NUL` character, so you need to add one to the buffer once you've read the string in:

```
mapNameChar = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * (mapNameLength + 1));   // Add +1
[data getBytes:mapNameChar range:NSMakeRange(start, mapNameLength)];
mapNameChar[mapNameLength] = '\0';            // Terminate with NUL
mapNameString = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:mapNameChar];
```

Better still forget about `malloc()` and the C-String and create the `NSString` directly from the `NSData` object:

```
mapNameString = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:(const char *)([data bytes]) + start
                                         length:mapNameLength
                                       encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Comment: Should be `sizeof(char) * (mapNameLength + 1)` for logical correctness.

Comment: Aha! Figured it'd be something silly ;) Either it's fixed or I've gotten really lucky the 50 times I just tried it. Thank you for saving me that headache!

Comment: @MikeBoch Please see the updated answer; you can forget about `malloc()`.

Comment: You'll meed to cast that `[data bytes]` to something concrete like `const char *` if you want to be able to do pointer arithmetic on it...

Comment: @Droppy Yes I see that. I hadn't been sure how to create a string with just a portion of the bytes. Didn't think of just adding to the pointer! That is a much better way. Thank you!